# Annotating a Figure using String with Strange Symbols

Tags: python, unicode, numpy, matplotlib

This should be something very simple to do, but I can't seem to find an answer in the forum anywhere. Here's the basic problem:

I have a set of CSV files of the form:

"X,Temp °C\n1,25\n..."

Note the degree symbol, that will be the heart of my problem. I'm using numpy and matplotlib and I import this file using:

```
GT_kwargs = dict(delimiter=',',names=True)
data_array = numpy.genfromtxt(filenm, **GT_kwargs)
```

This properly produces a numpy array with dtypes:

```
[('X', '<f8'), ('Temp_\xb0C', '<f8')]
```

So far so good. The data plots just fine, the problem comes when I want to annotate the curves using the names pulled from the header, in particular if I try to pass:

```
pyplot.annotate(data_array.dtype.names[1], xy=(1,1))
```

This throws:

ValueError: matplotlib display text must have all code points < 128 or use Unicode strings

Obviously the issue is \xb0C as the degree sign. I've tried replacing the symbol with a unicode string, but that does nothing. How do I change this string to get the annotation to include a degree symbol?

EDIT: I've narrowed down my question a little bit. How to I tell a string's encoding? It's a really basic question, but I still can't find the answer (which is often how it goes). A link to good documentation would be helpful.

Comment: how did you try to make the string unicode?

Comment: Part of the problem is that I'm new to using unicode. I'm having a hard time converting the string to unicode.

I've tried a bunch of dumb things like unicode(string) that all throw: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Things I have tried to convert this string (some are stupid):

'code'string = "T\xb0C",tmp=unicode(string),tmp=unicode(string,encoding="utf-8"),tmp=unicode(string,encoding="utf-16"),tmp=unicode(string,encoding="utf-32")

Comment: I figured it out: \xb0 is malformed UTF-8, which is why encoding wasn't working. So I replaced \xb0 with \xC2\xb0 and I could encode into unicode.

Comment: And apparently I can't close my own question... great.

Comment: should you answer your own question? I think it's better then a comment...

Comment: You should not close your question, but answer it! (and accept it when it will let you)

Comment: I wasn't allowed to answer my own question because I didn't have a high enough 'reputation', which was annoying because I had found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`\xb0` is malformed **utf-8**, which is the problem here. Replacing `\xb0` with `\xc2\xb0` allows **utf-8** to correctly encode the string.